# Logic to mirror byte value around 128

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a need to mirror a byte's value around the centre of 128.  So, example outputs of this function include:

```
In  0     Out  255
In  255   Out  0
In  128   Out  128
In  127   Out  129
In  30    Out  225
In  225   Out  30
```

I'm driving myself nuts with this, I'm sure I'll kick myself when I read the answers.

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure about 127 <=> 1?

Comment: Are you sure all those examples are correct ?

Comment: Sorry guys, the 127->1 example was wrong, corrected

Comment: Are the other values correct?  On one hand you appear to want the two's complement on an 8-bit value (see 128/128, and 127/129).  However, the others appear to be following the pattern of 255 - x (or bitwise not of x assuming 8-bit values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no obvious rule that matches your example output.

The first two and the last result could be explained by `255-n`, which might be a normal interpretation of ‘mirroring’ a byte. But 128->128 would have to be `256-n`, and 127->1 is seemingly inexplicable.

Comment: Used 255-n with a special condition for 128. Sorry about the weird 127->1 example.

Comment: @Kazar: You don't want a special case for 128 - since there are an even number of possible bytes, there is no "center" value, so no value should map to itself when you reverse them like this.  Eg: 255-127 is 128 (as it should be), not 129.  If you really want to flip all the values about 128, you should use `256-n`, in which case `255->1`, and nothing goes to 0 (since 256 does not fit into one byte)

Comment: The ‘center’ (mean) value for the range of bytes 0–255 is 127.5. `255-n` mirrors around 127.5. If you wanted to mirror around exactly 128, you'd end up with values 1–256, which is fine but it doesn't fit in a byte. To make it fit in a byte you might clip to map both `1->255` and `0->255`, which is at least less of a discontinuity than special-casing `128->128` when `129->126`.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer, which doesn't quite match your table, is `255 - v`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
In  0     Out  255
In  255   Out  0
In  128   Out  127
In  127   Out  128
In  30    Out  225
In  225   Out  30
```

It will be 255-n

Answer (score 0):

If you must stay within a byte, use `(255-v) + (v==255)?0:1`.  Otherwise, use `256-v`.  That mirrors around 128.  `~v` (bitwise not) may be faster than `255-v` if you want to mirror around 127.5.